# PHP in Mac OS X : Shows up the PHP code when opening the page

Tags: php, apache, macos

PHP Source Code is being shown up when opening PHP page in my localhost. This looks strange to me. I'm using using PHP 5.3.1 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.1 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2010 15:02:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

I'm running the default httpd webserver on my machine. The /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file has the following line to load php module:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

The httpd.conf file Syntax is OK.

```
$ httpd -t            
Syntax OK
```

am I missing something? Please suggest!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have handlers configured, something like: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5`

Comment: @rebus I've missed to include /private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf in httpd.conf file. It works now after adding it. I've spent lots of time to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add AddType to your server config:

```
AddType x-httpd-php .php
```

This can be added to the httpd.conf file, or even in an .htaccess file.

Comment: Actually, you need the AddHandler that rebus suggests in his comment.

Comment: I've missed to include `/private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf` in httpd.conf file. It works now after adding it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

For OS X Yosemite 10.10 need to add:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason why this is happening to you is because you're using short PHP tags `<?` instead of `<?php`

Either change that in all php files that are included or simply allow short PHP tags by adding `short_open_tag=On` in php.ini and then restart your apache server.